# VBA - Index / Match function with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing an issue when trying to compile a multiple criteria Index/Match code in VBA. This might be simple - but i am fairly new to VBA and nothing i have found around here worked.

Example:
I have a large amount of data in a specified range: `Sheets("CustomerAccounts").Range(CustomerSheetRange))` - I need VBA to return data from column titled "Values" by checking three criteria: Customer = X, Type = External, OriginCountry = UAE (columns are not adjacent in the original spreadsheet)
The criteria are stored in separate variables set by user of the macro beforehand.

```
Customer   | Type      | Origin        | Destination        |  Values
X          | Internal  | UAE           |  SA                |  Value 1
Y          | Internal  | UAE           |  SA                |  Value 2
X          | External  | UAE           |  SA                |  Value 3
X          | External  | ZA            |  UAE               |  Value 4
```

At the moment i have the following (quite bulky) code which finds the value using one criteria - OriginCountry variable.
The code searches for it in a pre-specified column - OriginCountryColumn.

```
ResultString = Application.Index(Sheets("CustomerAccounts").Range(CustomerSheetRange), Application.Match(OriginCountry, Sheets("CustomerAccounts").Range(OriginCountryColumn), 0), Application.Match("Values", Sheets("CustomerAccounts").Range(TitleRowCust), 0))
```

I would like to modify the code to also match the Type and The customer.
Is it possible to expand the above Index/Matxh function - or should i use a different approach?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: why not use a Pivot table or Autofilter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may walk through rows checking matches:

```
Dim row as Long
With Sheets("CustomerAccounts").Range(CustomerSheetRange))
    For row = 2 To .Rows.Count 'Starts in 2 to ignore header!
        If .Cells(row, costumerCol).Value Like costumerCriteria And .Cells(row, typeCol).Value Like typeCriteria And .Cells(row, originCol).Value Like originCriteria Then
            'This is a match!
            Debug.Print .Cells(row, valueCol)
        End if
    Next
End With
```

You must replace `costumerCol`, `typeCol`, `originCol` and `valueCol` with corresponding column number and `costumerCriteria`, `typeCriteria` and `originCriteria` with criteria specified.

If column indexes are also variable, make a search for them in first row before walking through rows.

Comment: Thank you, this approach is just the thing i needed.

Comment: This was a great approach! Thanks a ton. It fully replaced my hard code of  :)   This is what I had before: Range("E15").FormulaArray = "=INDEX('EMPLOYEE LIST'!A:P,MATCH(1,('EMPLOYEE LIST'!A:A=D5)*('EMPLOYEE LIST'!B:B=I5),0),12)"

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much, I'm new to VBA and couldn't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First, format the range containing your data to a Table (See http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/quick-start-create-an-excel-table-HA010359200.aspx on how to do that). Once done, use the following VBA code:

```
SomeCustomer = Range("...").Value
SomeType = Range("...").Value
SomeOrigin = Range("...").Value
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria=SomeCustomer
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria=SomeType
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria=SomeOrigin
```

Notes:

- You might have to customize this macro for your specific needs
- Name of table can be found/modified through Formulas>Name Manager
- ActiveSheet might be modified to the actual sheet you are using