# Index/Match Function Lookup Array with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I looked but could not find a valid response for this specific circumstance.

I need to write a macro that searches a table for a specific Name (Column A), Material (Column B), and Color (Column C) combination then returns the price from Column D.

I can enter in the formula (array)

```
=INDEX(Sht1!A1:D5552,MATCH(1,(Sht1!A1:A5552=A1)*(Sht1!B1:B5552=B1)*(Sht1!G1:G5552=C1),0),4)
```

Where A1 has the Name of the item I am searching for, B1 has the Material and C1 has the Color and the value returns just fine. However, I have set it up to quickly choose between Name/Material/Color and I want to be able to pull the prices quickly so I am trying to write a Macro to run when I click a button.

The problem I am encountering is transposing the MATCH(1,(Sht1!A1:A5552=A1)*(Sht1!B1:B5552=B1)*(Sht1!C1:C5552=C1),0)  part into VBA. I am trying to avoid just using the record function because it spits a .ForumlaArray out in R1C1 format that is difficult to interpret and update in the future.

I have tried

```
Application.Index(Sht1.Range("A1:D5552"), _
  Application.Match(1, Sht1.Range("A1:A5552") = Range("A1") & _
  "*" & Sht1.Range("B1:B5552") = Range("B1") & "*" & Sht1.Range("C1:C5552") = _
  Range("C1"), 0), 4)
```

But get a Type Mismatch

I also tried putting in the .ForumlaArray but get an "unable to set FormulaArray property of the range class" error (because it needs R1C1 Format)

```
"=INDEX(Sht1!A1:D5552,MATCH(1,(Sht1!A1:A5552=A1)*(Sht1!B1:B5552=B1)*(Sht1!C1:C5552=C1),0),4)"
```

I have variables set up a little differently but I am trying to simplify these examples to make it easier to interpret.

Comment: I think that VBA is overkill for what you are trying to do here. Just to make sure: your intended solution is to be able to select the Name, Material, and Color, and have the Price returned when a button is clicked, correct? What is it about VBA you believe will make selecting these faster?

Comment: I'm confused by how VBA would make this faster?  Don't you just need to update the cells that hold the Name, Material, and Color being searched for?

Comment: I have a list of 600+ names each with multiple Materials/Types (over 5000 possibilities). In addition I have 6 separate price lists. I am making a form with dependent dropdowns to easily locate the Name/Mat/Color followed by a button that will fill out the Specifications then list the price from each list for that item. I am setting it up so if I need the prices for 6 items from multiple lists I can easily select them and pull the prices. I am assuming VBA is the easiest method for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the `Application.Match` function and some fundamentals of VBA.  In short, the function does not work like the Formula does.

AFAIK `Application.Match` takes a value to look for, and a 1D range of cells to look for it and returns the index of the cell in the array.  So it sounds like you will need to do it multiple times to for each column. Granted, I can't find any [acceptable documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873(v=office.15).aspx) on it.

A correct usage would be:

```
row_index = Application.Match(Sht1.Range("A1").Value, Sht1.Range("A1:A5552"), 0)
price_value = Sht1.Cells(row_index, "D").Value
```

But that will only return the first match, not all of them. VBA won't increase performance if all you are doing is using replicating the formula in VBA.  Other posters are correct that a different approach might be necessary.

---

Some other fundamentals you are getting wrong mostly stem from you taking the formula string and trying to translate it directly into `Application.Match` which AFAIK you can't do.

You are trying to specify conditions of when you have a match like this:

```
Sht1.Range("A1:A5552") = Range("A1")
```

What you are really doing is trying to compare Ranges.  VBA is trying to evaluate this as a boolean before passing it to `Application.Match`.  This returns a Type Error because the ranges are of different dimensions.

In case you didn't already do this: `Sht1` needs to be declared as a `Worksheet` object and set to `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sht1")`

```
Dim Sht1 As WorkSheet
Set Sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sht1")
```

you can't simply hope that the variable `Sht1` already refers to the worksheet "Sht1".

Then you try to string these together like this.

```
Sht1.Range("A1:A5552") = Range("A1") & "*" & _
Sht1.Range("B1:B5552") = Range("B1") & "*" & _
Sht1.Range("C1:C5552") = Range("C1")
```

I think you understand that `&` is for string concatenation but you are trying to concatenate, the strings `"*"` with the booleans/ranges which is undefined.

### A VBA Solution

If you want a solution using VBA, you can either walk through all rows until you find a match:

```
Function FindProduct(name As String, material As String, color As String) As String

    Dim product_sheet As WorkSheet
    Set product_sheet = GetProductSheet() ' Workbooks(BOOK_NAME).Sheets(SHEET_NAME)

    Dim row_index as Long
    For row_index = 2 To product_sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If product_sheet.Cells(row_index, NAME_COL).Value = name _
        And product_sheet.Cells(row_index, MATERIAL_COL).Value = material _
        And product_sheet.Cells(row_index, COLOR_COL).Value = color Then

            FindProduct = product_sheet.Cells(row_index, PRODUCT_COL).Value
            Exit Function

        End If

    Next row_index

End Function
```

Or if performance is an issue:

- Keep your data sorted on columns "A", "B", "C" (for this example, in that order.)
- Find the range of rows that match in column "A"
- From that range, find the sub range of rows that match in column "B"
- From that range, return the sub range of rows that match in column "C"

I may provide that later.

Comment: In essence my question gets down to how to format the Application.Match function. Where the formula is Formatted as Match(Lookup_value, Lookup_array, [col]) I want to test multiple criteria for it's Lookup_array in order to return a Boolean True value (1) as the Lookup_value so that Match will give me the row number for the Index function.

Comment: Sht1 is defined, I didn't record it to keep the example simpler. If I can't combine the functions then I would record the Match value as a variable and then write the Index function separately referencing the variable, would that work better ? I really appreciate your input.

Comment: First I thought the INDEX function returned an index not a value.  I never use and and you don't need it for VBA.  You simply can't use `Application.Match` with multiple criteria. See [vba-index-match-function-with-multiple-criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462810/vba-index-match-function-with-multiple-criteria).  I recommend sorting your data and walking through until you find a match.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off with a completely different approach. Instead of having VBA doing the lookup, I would use VBA to maintain lists of unique values in your table columns, each contained in a named range. Then use Data Validation to create a drop down menu for each search item (Name, Material, Color) populated by the VBA created named range, and continue to use the array formula you presented above to perform the actual lookup.

See Jean-François Corbett's answer for how to [Populate unique values in to VBA array from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890257/populate-unique-values-in-to-vba-array-from-excel).

Using a `Table` combined with [structured references](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx), you can add more entries to the bottom of your `Table` and it will auto-magically expand to include them. Set your VBA code to build the new list of unique values (and store them in named ranges, e.g. `NamesList`, `MaterialsList`, `ColorList`) when the `Table` changes.

Another option would be to simply use a Pivot Table.

EDIT: [Here's another nice approach](http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/retrieving-unique-values-from-a-range-or-array/) to building a list of unique values from a `Range`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I am completely unfamiliar with this approach so I am going to have to tinker with it to see how it works.