# Index Matching with 5 criteria - changing to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In my search so far, this is probably the most closely aligned to my current problem: [VBA - Index / Match function with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462810/vba-index-match-function-with-multiple-criteria)

My workbook consists of:

- 6 worksheets uniquely named, each with around 80 rows and 50 columns (with 
  unique variations)
- One 'Master Sheet' which contains all the data I require to input into the 
  other 6 worksheets

[Sample Target Sheet e.g. 1 of 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4gub.jpg)

[Master Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaHAp.jpg)

I am currently using an INDEX MATCH to return the value I want, but it is painstakingly slow and impractical.

Formula:

> =IFERROR(INDEX('Master Sheet'!$A:$H,MATCH(1,('Master Sheet'!$D:$D=E$3)*('Master Sheet'!$F:$F=$C6)*('Master Sheet'!$A:$A=E$2)*('Master Sheet'!$C:$C=E$1)*('Master Sheet'!$G:$G=E$4),0),8),"")

I have attempted to translate this into VBA, and while it runs, it doesn't return anything. I also need to add in a loop so it cycles through the columns, and when complete, moves on to the next sheet.

Loop example where the first sheet I want it to look at is number 3:

```
For i = 3 To Sheets.Count
        stream = Sheets(i).Name
        Worksheets(stream).Activate
```

The full code I have:

```
Sub PopulateWithNewMasterSheet()

Dim row As Long
Dim k As Long
k = 2

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:AV")
    For row = 6 To .Rows.Count
        If .Cells(1, "E").Value Like Sheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, "C") And .Cells(2, "E").Value Like Sheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, "A") And .Cells(3, "E").Value Like Sheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, "D") And .Cells(4, "E").Value Like Sheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, "G") And .Cells(row, "C").Value Like Sheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, "F") Then
            'This is a match!
            .Cells(row, "E") = Sheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, "H")
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code at all? Try stepping through your code with F8 and see what happens. My strong suspicion is that your 'If X and Y and Z" is failing and, thus, goes to the next entry but never succeeds. This will indeed return nothing. I strongly advise checking that the conditions are succeeding first, but beyond that, you may also want to nest them to ensure that it evaluates one, and then the next, and so on. Otherwise condition A could return False, but it still is forced to check B-Z before skipping (which is time consuming).

Comment: Thanks Brandon will give it a try.