# Index / Match Horizontal Data With Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to get this horizontal data table transposed into an easier to read vertical format. Through VBA, I'm able to get it unpivoted so that each ID # is on its own line.

Basically names are visited between 1 and 3 times checking for malfunction. If there is a malfunction, it is visited a second time for repair, and a third time if that repair fails. Pictures are taken at each visit, so a single component may have three sets of picture #s.

I think the best way to do this will be through an Index/Match, but I'm having difficulty getting started. I'm working primarily with cells E20:H23.

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18462810/4961700

Comment: Have you searched here "VBA unpivot"?

Comment: Yes I have and I have it able to unpivot it and get each name/ID # combination on its own row. What I am really hoping to do, would be to have a formula in F20 (for example) that will search the horizontal array, find where Bob #1 was visited for the first time and pull in the Initial Pic #. I imagine this code could be easily manipulated to fit the rest of the variables.